# Data in Excel sheet from more than 1 DB

Tags: mysql

We have a query in excel sheet (returning data from mysql) which is based out of a database, see below a sample DSN:

```
DATABASE=myDB;DESCRIPTION=myDB;DSN=myDB-dsn;OPTION=0;PORT=3306;SERVER=myServer;UID=user1;
```

This works satisfactorily as long as it is from multiple tables but from a single DB.

Is it possible to get data in an Excel sheet by having a query from 2 databases?

I can create 2 separate DSNs, 2 separate queries, but the challenge is:
if there is a common field (unrelated) on these 2 DBs, can we have 1 query and 1 data returned?
can the whole of it done without any manual copy-paste involved?
If it was Oracle I heard DBLinks could help , but doesn't seem to be available in MySQL.
**Update**
I was looking for more like:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM db1.table1 A LEFT JOIN db2.table1 B ON A.id = B.id
```

Not sure if this kind of references are possible. Even though by query it will work, I am not sure how to define a DSN for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can access table of another db like

```
SELECT cols FROM DBNAME.TABLE_NAME
```

Have this as a procedure in myDB and call it from myDB